# .htaccess adding language support for shop

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, multilingual

I'm trying to create multilingual shop having RewriteRules as follows:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [L]
    RewriteRule .*[^/]$                 $0/ [R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com\$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       $1?language=en [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^catalog/product/([^/]*)/$      catalog/index.php?id=$1  [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)/$          catalog/index.php?category=$1  [L,QSA]
```

Those rules don't work when trying to access http://example.com/catalog/product/111/
or http://example.com/catalog/category/

However when I delete

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com\$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       $1?language=en [QSA]
```

everything works just fine.

What is the problem? How can I make this stuff work together?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the order of the rules, and get rid of the L flag for some of them. This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/product/([^/]*)/      catalog/index.php?id=$1  [QSA,S=1]
RewriteRule ^catalog/([^/]*)/          catalog/index.php?category=$1  [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       $1?language=en [QSA]
```

Comment: that works, if I wouldn't have some more rules :) It was my mistake not to post them here. I've updated my rules according to my .htaccess

Comment: The other rules shouldn't interfere with this. One other thing I spotted is that in your RewriteCond you have a backslash before the $ sign - you don't want that in there. That's probably what's preventing it from matching.